# dictionary with tuple as key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Currently I created a dictionary that uses tuple pairs as keys. My dictionary currently counts pairs such as (a,b) and (b,a) separately, but I ultimately want (a,b) == (b,a).

Currently that portion of my code looks like this:

```
final = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a,b in pairs:

    final[(a[0],b[0])].append((a[2],a[1]))
    final[(b[0],a[0])].append((b[2],b[1]))
```

Would I have to check if the (b,a) of the (a,b) already exists in the dictionary prior to adding it? Or do I fix the dictionary after it's all completed?

Comment: So you don't want any repeats?

Comment: yes. I would like it to add the values to the (a,b) key if it's (a,b) or (b,a), without creating a (b,a) key if possible

Comment: In the `(a,b)` key, are `a` and `b` ever equal to each other?

Comment: @Hello you mean add it to the dictionary, not the key, right?

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as Alex Hall. Another approach is to use a sorted tuple for the key, eg `key = (a,b) if a<b else (b,a)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `frozenset([a, b])`. Sets compare equal regardless of order, but only frozensets can be used as dictionary keys because they're immutable.

If `a == b` though your key will be equal to `frozenset([a])`. If this is a problem, we can make a plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = [frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([3,4]), frozenset([2,1]), 
frozenset([5,6]), frozenset([7,8]), frozenset([6,5])]

for pair in pairs:
    pair_count.update({pair: pair_count.get(pair, 0) + 1})

pair_count
{frozenset([5, 6]): 2, frozenset([1, 2]): 2, frozenset([8, 7]): 1, frozenset([3, 4]): 1}
```